# C# Add all TextBoxes in a Form

Tags: c#, winforms

Say I have 100 textboxes on one form. Numbers go into these textboxes.

I want one button to click, and it will discard all the empty textboxes, and add all the ones which have a number inside of them.

How would I be able to?

So far. This is the code I got. How would I make it add all them up though.

```
    foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
    {
        if (c is TextBox)
        {
            TextBox textBox = c as TextBox;
            if (textBox.Text != string.Empty)
            {
                //add!
            }
        }
```

Comment: [I have 100 textboxes on one form](http://i.stack.imgur.com/fvdkb.png)

Comment: I promise. It is nothing like that. At all! I am a firm believer of a nice clean UI. Though, it does seem like it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For mass data entry you should consider using a `DataGrid` instead of a `TextBox` - this is because in WinForms, controls are expensive - they are individual `hWnd` objects managed by User32 - so your form will be somewhat sluggish, and slow to repaint itself if all 100 textboxes are visible on-screen at the same time.

(Indeed, you should look at using WPF for building your UI as it handles high-DPI better and uses "windowless" hardware accelerated graphics).

Anyway, you'll want a tree-traversal function to retrieve all of the textboxes, like in @Muhammad's answer, then remove them. I note that you cannot use Muhammad's answer directly because you cannot remove controls as you iterate through a control collection, so try this:

```
public static IEnumerable<Control> GetDescendantControls(this Control control)
{
    Stack<Control> stack = new Stack<Control>();
    stack.Push( control );
    while( stack.Count > 0 )
    {
        Control c = nodes.Pop();
        yield return c;
        foreach( Control child in c.Controls ) stack.Push( child );
    }
}


List<Control> allEmptyTextBoxControls = this.GetDescendantControls()
    .OfType<TextBox>()
    .Where( c => String.IsNullOrWhitespace( c.Text ) )
    .ToList();

foreach(Control c in allEmptyTextBoxControls ) c.Parent.Controls.Remove( c );
```